# ImportError when I change the directory in cmd

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am trying to import sklearn using cmd, I am changing the directory to a folder where I saved previous python files, however, I can't import sklearn in that particular folder and this is what I get:

```py
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\VER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\VER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Users\VER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import _joblib
  File "C:\Users\VER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_joblib.py", line 22, in <module>
    from ..externals import joblib
  File "C:\Users\VER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\__init__.py", line 119, in <module>
    from .parallel import Parallel
  File "C:\Users\VER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 28, in <module>
    from ._parallel_backends import (FallbackToBackend, MultiprocessingBackend,
  File "C:\Users\VER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .executor import get_memmapping_executor
  File "C:\Users\VER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\executor.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .externals.loky.reusable_executor import get_reusable_executor
  File "C:\Users\VER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\loky\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ._base import Executor, Future
  File "C:\Users\VER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\loky\_base.py", line 22, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures import wait, as_completed
  File "C:\Users\VER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\concurrent\futures\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures.process import ProcessPoolExecutor
  File "C:\Users\VER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 52, in <module>
    from queue import Full
ImportError: cannot import name 'Full'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file or folder is occupying a python file's namespace, for example, 'time.py'.
In this case, it is 'queue.py'

You need to remove it or you will not be able to import the module.

This is because python defaults to importing from the folder containing the program, and you must have a file overwriting 'queue.py' there.

I myself have experienced the error when attempting to import matplotlib into a file named 'copy', as a deep, deep dependency of matplotlib was named 'copy.py'

Comment: I have a _pycache_ folder in that folder, but how do I do what you are proposing ?

Comment: In particular, I think OP should make sure there are no files named `queue.py` anywhere on his path, except for the built-in module by that name.

Comment: @IssacNewton I would check the pycache folder, or totally clear the folder apart from your script

Comment: ah!! now I get it!, I have a file named queue.py in that folder and it is just an implementation of a Queue datastructure in Python, but it seems like the name queue.py accidentally caused import problems

Comment: Install these via `python -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose` and see if you get the same problem

Comment: @Barb Installing the dependencies might cause more ImportErrors, he needs to remove his conflicting files first

Comment: the dependencies are satisfied, the problem was that I had a queue.py file in that folder and python was trying to import from it instead of the queue.py that belongs to the sklearn library. I changed the file's name and everything worked fine.